# Java 8 Iterating Stream Operations

Tags: java, queue, java-8

I want to perform a stream where the output from the stream is then used as the source for the same stream, in the same operation.

I currently perform this sort of operation using a queue; I remove an item, process it, and add any results that need further processing back to the queue. Here are two examples of this sort of thing:

```
Queue<WorkItem> workQueue = new Queue<>(workToDo);
while(!workQueue.isEmpty()){
    WorkItem item = workQueue.remove();
    item.doOneWorkUnit();
    if(!item.isDone()) workQueue.add(item);
}

Queue<Node> nodes = new Queue<>(rootNodes);
while(!nodesLeft.isEmpty()){
    Node node = nodes.remove();
    process(node);
    nodes.addAll(node.children());
}
```

I would imagine that the first could be performed concurrently like this:

```
try {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkItem> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Stream<WorkItem> reprocess = Stream.generate(() -> workQueue.remove()).parallel();

    Stream.concat(workToDo.parallelstream(), reprocess)
          .filter(item -> {item.doOneWorkUnit(); return !item.isDone();})
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> workQueue));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){}
```

And the second as:

```
try {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Node> reprocessQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Stream<WorkItem> reprocess = Stream.generate(() -> nodes.remove()).parallel();

    Stream.concat(rootNodes.parallelStream(), reprocess)
          .filter(item -> {process(item); return true;})
          .flatMap(node -> node.children().parallelStream())
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> reprocessQueue));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){}
```

However, these feel like kludgy workarounds, and I dislike having to resort to using exceptions. Does anyone have a better way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: I would be frankly quite surprised if you could make this work in any way.  I would not expect this to work.

Comment: I agree with Louis. It just doesn't match the streams paradigm.

Comment: Why don't you run the composition of two operations as a single one? I mean, if you'd like to do something like `x; y = f(x); z = f(y); return z`, then you could do just `return f(f(x))`.

Comment: @cdshines The number of compositions is an unknown. Also I would assume that OP doesn't want to devote all the CPU time to one item at once.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, well, from what I see, neither does the OP use intermediate results. As for the unknown number of compositions - I guess, one could simply apply some kind of a loop conditioned by `isDone()`... Oh wait, I just understood what you meant when you said about the streams paradigm :)

Comment: OP, have you already considered the Fork/Join framework? The concept of the Work Queue is first-class there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, and that is what I would use if I were actually writing code to process work units like that; I just included it as an example.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually, I just figured out why exactly that solution wouldn't work - the `NoSuchElementException` could be thrown any time there are more worker threads running than there are items. You would need to use the `take()` method, in combination with some type of deadlock detection, in order to actually finish at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make work parallel, I would use standard `java.util.concurrent.Executor`. To return the task back to working queue, in the end of the code of each task, add `executor.execute(this)`.